# Redirected Too Many Times Error [PHP & MySQL]

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to help out my friend with a problem consisting PHP and MySQL.  It's been about 3-4 months since I've done PHP/MySQL at all, so I need some help identifying the problem.  The following code produces the error informing the user that localhost has redirected too many times:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login
</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
<?php
require('db.php');
session_start();
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = stripslashes($username);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
//Checking is user existing in the database or not
$md5pass = md5($passowrd);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and     password='$md5pass'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($rows==1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
}else{
echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
}
}else{
?>
<div class="form">
  <h1>Log In
  </h1>
  <form action="" method="post" name="login">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
  </form>
  <p>Not registered yet? 
    <a href='registration.php'>Register Here
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
<?php } ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Yes, I do realize the security issues about the code. I will inform about those issues to my friend, but for now, I only want to figure out why the code is redirecting many times, while it should be redirecting only once.**

I suspect that it's something related to the fact that the `header()` function is used after multiple outputs, or the php section isn't closed properly.

Comment: What is the name of this file index. php?

Comment: the `header()` function should come before your `<!DOCTYPE`, I guess

Comment: ^ turn on error reporting because this should be spitting out some

Comment: @SamOrozco My friend currently isn't online, but I'm not sure if the file name would affect it's functionality.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes All I know is that there shouldn't be any outputs before a `header()` function.

Comment: If it's index.php I can see this calling it self then calling itself,  etc.. That's why I was curious

Comment: @nogad The error doesn't specify why localhost is redirecting infinitely.

Comment: @SamOrozco I actually didn't think of that possibility.  I'll go check with my friend.

Comment: Unset $_POST before the header that should fix it

Comment: thats a browser\server error, ther are php code errors, your not displaying

Comment: @SamOrozco what exactly to you mean by "unsetting" $_POST?

Comment: unset($_POST) OR $_POST =null. So you don't go into the if statement again

Comment: @SamOrozco Thanks for the advice.  I'll have my friend try out your recommendations.  Also, if your advice works, you can use it as an answer to this post.  I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Ok awesome!  Glad we could help.  Let us know

Comment: The HTML part is some kind of output. The browser shouldn't receive anything before the headers.

Comment: @SamOrozco So, the problem was that there was a `header()` function in `index.php` that led back to `login.php`, so it was basically a loop my friend didn't even notice. I have no idea what to do with this post anymore.    I'll probably just delete this post soon.

Comment: Don't delete the post. It goes bad against your acount and can stop you fron asking future questions. Just post the answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: @SamOrozco I never knew that.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an `if` statement in `index.php` that contained a `header()` function that led back to the login page.  It was basically a loop.